# @model IEnumerable siempre es null

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, core

Estoy tratando de recuperar los registros desde una tabla hacia una vista pero pese a que existen registros el Modelo es nulo.

Estoy ocupando VS2019 en una aplicación Web ASP.Net Core con .NET 5.0

En la vista Index tengo lo siguiente, realice una validacion @if (Model != null && Model.Count()) ya pense que me daba error por que la tabla estaba vacia pero ahora ya tiene datos y Model sigue dando vacio (null).

```html
@model IEnumerable<CfgDashboard.Models.DefEvento>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Definición de eventos del Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>Lista de definiciones de eventos</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a class="btn btn-success d-block" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="DefEventos">Agregar</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table class="table table-bordered table.striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Id)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Nombre)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Descripcion)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ReglaAsociada)</td>
                        <!-- 
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FechaIngreso)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FechaActualizacion)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UltimoUsuario)</td>
                        -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Id</td>
                            <td>@item.Nombre</td>
                            <td>@item.Descripcion</td>
                            <td>@item.ReglaAsociada</td>
                            <!--
                            <td>@item.FechaIngreso</td>
                            <td>@item.FechaActualizacion</td>
                            <td>@item.UltimoUsuario</td>
                            -->
                            <td>
                                <a asp-controller="Def.eventos" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-i="@item.Id" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                                <a asp-controller="Def.eventos" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-i="@item.Id" class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No existen registros</p>
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar sacar este error.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Comprobaste que el modelo esté llegando a la vista con los datos correctos?

Comment: ¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: No le estas pasando la lista como parametro al View(), por eso te sale null.

Comment: Gracias eso era... estoy recien empazando con esta tecnologia!

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de Index estoy recibiendo datos se aprecia en la 1° imagen.

Pero al momento de ejecutar la vista el index.cshtml la variable Model es vacía (2° imagen)

El Create me funciona correctamente.

Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]